# AngularJS routing issue bad url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-ng-route

Have generate my route in my app:

```
app.config( function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl: './partials/home/home.html',
            controller: 'mainCtrl'}
        )
        .when('/article',{
            templateUrl: './partials/article/article.html',
            controller: 'articleCtrl'}
        )
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
    });

});
```

It's working !

But link was bas :( 
I create my link like that :

```
<div class="read-more"><a href="#article">Lire plus...</a></div>
```

my bad link: 
http://localhost:10001/#!/#article

vs the good link was : 
http://localhost:10001/#!/article

Who was wrong ?

thx

PS I use node lite-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This http://localhost:10001/#!/article is the right url.

The reason being, if the browser is HTML5 browser AngularJS will redirect it to `#!`

Otherwise it will be only `#`.

Read this [documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) on `$location` to find out more on why this happens.

> - Opening a regular URL in a legacy browser -> redirects to a hashbang URL
> - Opening hashbang URL in a modern browser -> rewrites to a regular URL